# trefoil knot and meridian/longitudinal cycles

Tags: algebraic-topology, homological-algebra, knot-theory

I hope this is a simple question...

For the trefoil knot 3_1, whose knot group is given by a presentation of the fundamental group, $\pi_1(M) = \langle a,b: aba = bab \rangle$, where the meridian and longitude cycles can be identified as,

$$m = a,$$

$$l = ba^2ba^{-4}$$

I understand the presentation, and have actually worked them out with Wirtinger(spelling?), but the thing I don't understand is how these cycles are identified.

I know that a and b refer to $\rho(a)$ and $\rho(b)$, where these are commuting (brought into Jordan form) complex 2x2 matrices in $SL_2(C)$ representing the cycles.

I guess I just don't understand how these cycles are 'identified'...

Comment: Are you asking how you prove that $m=a$ and $l=ba^2ba^{-4}$? Where does $SL_2(\mathbb C)$ come into the picture? Are you thinking of a representation of the knot group into $SL_2(\mathbb C)$?

Comment: Yes, I am asking how $m=a$ and $l=ba^2ba^{-4}$. Here $m$ is the contractible loop. I guess the other information was to try and help context...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[image]
Okay, here's my picture of the trefoil and derivation of the wirtinger presentation that you already worked out. Any curve in the knot complement starting at the basepoint (near the X in my picture) will pick up a Wirtinger generator every time the curve passes under the appropriate arc. So the meridian, regarded as a small loop around the arc with an X, picks up an $a$, giving you the $m=a$. The longitude is defined to be a parallel copy of the knot with trivial linking number. If you run an obvious parallel arc to the knot, it has linking number $\pm3$ the way I've drawn it, so I added three twists to cancel out this linking number. So I read off $\ell=baca^{-3}$ as I travel around the red curve, which is $\ell=ba(aba^{-1})a^{-3}=ba^2ba^{-4}$, as desired.

Comment: So two things I notice: 1.) choice of starting point X (being at "a") is arbitrary, and 2.) leaving X in the direction shown, one passes through the "b" loop first, then the "a" loop, etc., picking up a "ba...", as opposed to "ac..." - which was by `reading off the sign posts along the road and not counting the signs on the loops.... (Does that make sense?) 

Very good explanation though and great effort!

Comment: @Nate: yes the basepoint is chosen based on the fact that you said $a$ was the meridian.  Also, I don't understand what you are saying in 2). Are you saying my calculation is wrong? As you travel along the red arc from the basepoint you pass under b followed by a followed by c, giving you $bac=baaba^{-1}$ followed by $a^{-3}$ for the twists, so I think it is correct as stated.

Comment: Sorry, no, I was just wrong in my thinking of #2, I agree and it also concurs with what I have read about this knot.